# Manipulate a data series Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array Say, `@array1 = qw (1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,1)`. From this array I have to extract an output as `"1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6"` (i.e. to remove the number of 1's from the end alone). In-fact I tried different methods suggestion for other similar questions, but I couldn't get to it. I am new to Perl, please do help me out.

P.S.: Series can be in any order. Not necessarily ascending, can be any random number in-between the 1's. Between the value '5' & '6', as demonstrated below, there will not be any 1's either. Say:

```
my @array1 = (1,1,1,5,3,4,4,4,2,6,1,1,1,1,1);
```

Expected output:

```
(1,1,1,5,3,4,4,4,2,6)
```

Vague steps, but couldn't get to where I wanted:

```
my $file = "emm4.txt"; #emm4.txt contains 1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,1

open (FH, "< $file") or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
my @lines;
while (<FH>) {
push (@lines, $_);
}    
sub UniqueValues {
my %seen;
return grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @_;
   }  
my @unique;
@unique = UniqueValues(@lines);
print @unique;

close FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!";
```

Comment: What are the rules? Do you want to always remove the `1` at the end?

Comment: Yes, i need to remove only the 1's at the end. It is not necessary that number of 1's at the end is 3, it can be any number of times. 

Eg:- @array1 = qw (1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,1,1,1). From this array i have to extract an output as "1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6"

Comment: Please be more accurate with your question. ` qw(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,1)` will raise a warning message and create just a single array element, and `"1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6"` is a string, not a list. Please post an example of your data file

Comment: My sincere apologies, i am very new to perl and hence so. Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: @DarshanSrinivasan: Please stop fixing your question to remove the errors: it makes nonsense of the solutions that you have been offered

Answer (score 0):

Your `UniqueValues` function is correct.  The problem is probably in your handling of the input.  A quick way to debug this (besides using the built-in debugger) is to dumper that value contents of `@lines`  with something like JSON, YAML, or some other serialization format that targets text.  You simplicity's sake, I will use the `Data::Dumper` module since it is part of Core Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $file = "emm4.txt"; #emm4.txt contains 1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,1

# always use the three argument version of open or you have a 
# a security hole (see open's documentation for more)
# also, bareword filehandles have issues, lexical filehandles
# are better
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";

my @lines;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line; #this is needed or there will be a newline at the end of the line
    push (@lines, $line);
}

print Dumper \@lines;
```

If this does not print

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          1,
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          4,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          1,
          1,
          1
        ];
```

Then you have done something wrong with the data from the file.  From your comment you seem to indicate that the file contains "1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1,1,1", if so, then you probably need to look into the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function.

Comment: Sure Chas. Owens, i will look into the Split function. Just to give more clarity, 

Series can be in any order. Not necessarily ascending, can be any random number in-between the 1's. Between the value '5' & '6', as demonstrated below, there will not be any 1's either. 

Say, my @array1 = (1,1,1,5,3,4,4,4,2,6,1,1,1,1,1);                                Expected output = (1,1,1,5,3,4,4,4,2,6)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which has nothing to do with uniqueness

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

From your comments it looks like you need to reduce trailing array values until the final value is unique

Try this, but note that it will remove *any* duplicate values. For instance `6 1 5 2 4 3 7 7 7` will be reduced to `6 1 5 2 4 3 7`, and `9 1 1 1 1 1 3` will be left unchanged

```
use 5.014;

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 1 1 1 );

say "@array";

pop @array while @array > 1 and $array[-1] == $array[-2];

say "@array";
```

**output**

```
1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 1 1 1
1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 1
```

---

**Original**

It looks like all you need is

```
pop @array1 while $array1[-1] == 1;
```

But your input is confused and I can't tell how to fix it unless you show an accurate example of your data file

Are the numbers in the file one per line? Then all you need to do is `chomp @array1` after the read loop

Is there just one line in the file with comma-separated numbers? Then you just need `@array1 = /\d+/g`

Comment: Thankyou @Borodin, it worked for me. I got (1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6) as output. 

One quick doubt, In-case i need to get (1,1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,1), i just have to add '1' at the end, i used push as below. Is there any shorter way to address the same.? Good day & thanks again.

pop array while $array[-1] == 1; #.Gave 1,1,1,5,3,4,4,4,2,6 as expected.

push $array,1; #,Gave me 1,1,1,5,3,4,4,4,2,6,1

Comment: @DarshanSrinivasan: Are you saying that you want to reduce multiple occurrences of `1` at the end to a single `1`? It looks like you've done it in two statements; do you need it to run even faster? By the way, please publish code by editing your question. It is unreadable in comments

Comment: Yes, correct. I want to reduce multiple occurrences of 1 at the end to a single 1. Updates the question with your suggestion as well.

Comment: @DarshanSrinivasan: Please leave your question untouched unless your original phrasing is completely wrong. It's now looking like you should ask a completely new question, but you *must* specify the requirement much better

Comment: Oops, i edited since you asked me to publish code by editing the question as it is unreadable in comments . My apologies.

Comment: @DarshanSrinivasan: I also apologise. You should always *add* to your question when editing it. Correcting errors that are adressed in comments or solutions puts them out of context

Comment: No problem. For my learning purpose, I want to reduce multiple occurrences of 1 at the end to a single 1. How can i efficiently write a code without a push.?

Comment: @DarshanSrinivasan: My update does as you ask. You shouldn't be trying to optimise until your application is complete and you have found it to be too slow. Then you run it through a profiler and find where the bottlenecks are